# Format external hard drive to ext4 in command line

Tags: command-line, external-hdd, ext4, format

How do you format an external hard drive to ext4 via the command line in ubuntu?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The command is `mkfs.ext4`, see its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4).

If you are ok with the default settings(1), it's just

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/yourpartitionhere
```

---

*Footnotes:*

(1) from the man page:

> The defaults of the parameters for the newly created filesystem, if
>   not overridden by the options listed below, are controlled by the
>   /etc/mke2fs.conf configuration file. See the mke2fs.conf(5) manual
>   page for more details.

Comment: Okay thanks. How do you get the device information? Like the command to know if it is /dev/sda or /dev/sdb?

Comment: Never mind i got it..its  `sudo fdisk -l` . Thanks

Comment: May also need to use fdisk fist to setup the partitions
sudo fdisk /dev/sdx -> d -> n -> 1 -> enter -> enter -> w
then the above
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdx1
depending on the partitions, it should be /dev/sdx1 most likely it is not /dev/sdx